# Scraping insides of modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, bookmarklet

I am successfully scraping and pulling everything I want (for the most part). My issue is that when I dynamically click to open a modal, it clicks open but I can't scrape anything that's inside of it.

```
 var q = document;
```

That's how I was accessing the document in the beginning of the project, when I'm scraping all the other data. I've been trying to scrape the insides of the modal by just creating a new variable and accessing the document, but I think my issue is that the source code isn't updating when the modal pops up. This would mean that when I'm trying to scrape certain HTML elements, they don't technically exist. Is there a way for me to access this new code??

I'm sorry there isn't much code in this question, but bookmarklets don't really have a whole lot to them!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should just add a small pause before scraping. Here is an example for this link https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form:

```
javascript:(function() {
    window.frames[0].document.getElementById("create-user").click();
    window.setTimeout("alert(window.frames[0].document.querySelector(\"div[class='ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable']\").outerHTML);", 2000);
})();
```

Comment: So the .setTimeout() function would force the code to pause before continuing the scrape?

Comment: No, it didn't. I've also tried creating a new instance of the window to scrape when the modal pops up by using document.window = "url" but that's not working either.

Comment: Not good news. If you are OK with installing an additional extension (and, certainly, open to master it), try to use the free add-ons such as ['iMacros for Chrome'](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome) or (rather powerful one) ['iMacros for Firefox'](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox). Related Q&A's on 'stakoverflow' are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imacros).